# Expo app crashes after splash screen in .apk, but works perfectly on the expo go App

Tags: react-native, expo

I created an expo app and it's running completely fine in expo go app but when I make build (apk) using the command

```
npx eas build -p android --profile preview
```

and install in my phone. It opens but closes automatically after displaying splash screen. I've tried multiple time so please help. Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "tal-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.18.2",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.11",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.20",
    "expo": "~49.0.15",
    "expo-app-loading": "^2.1.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.6",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-circular-progress": "^1.3.9",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.11.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.6.3",
    "react-native-select-dropdown": "^3.4.0",
    "react-native-status-bar-height": "^2.6.0",
    "react-native-step-indicator": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-svg": "^13.9.0",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I want to get an working apk build of this app. Any help would be appreciated.

- I tried debugging that, but I didn't find the problem, I except a working app